# Making assertions on Jest manual mocks

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm having some trouble with manual Jest mocks and could use some help.

The file I am testing looks something like this:

```
import withTranslation from '../utils/withTranslation'

withTranslation('test')
```

I'm mocking a module in a test file like this.

```
import withTranslation from '../utils/withTranslation'

jest.mock('../utils/withTranslation')

// tests here
```

I have the manual mock at `../utils/__mocks__/withTranslation.js` with the following code:

```
const impl = (...args) => {
  console.log('in mock', args)
  return args
}

export default impl
```

When the test runs, the mock is used and I can see the console log.  So far so good.

However, I want to be able to make assertions on the usage of withTranslation when it is mocked.  For example, `expect(withTranslation).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')`.

So, I change the manual mock to be a Jest mock function with the same implementation as before.

```
const impl = (...args) => {
  console.log('in mock 1', args)
  return args
}

// only difference is wrapping in jest.fn()
export default jest.fn(impl)
```

When the test runs now, a generic Jest mock function is used and I DO NOT see the console log, so my fake implementation is never called.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in my question is correct.  The reason this was happening is because my test suite had a global beforeEach which was calling jest.resetMocks().  Hopefully this saves someone a few hours.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The function `withTranslation` in the actual module is already replaced with the mock before the test begins and this replacement is **not** done via reference. Hence when you assert the mock `withTranslation` the assertion fails because the mocked function is never called but rather the `withTranslation` method in the actual module is called.

Your console log still appears because as I said above the "real" module's function has already been replaced with the mock.

So import the actual `withTranslation` and assert it and it will resolve your problem.

Credit to this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40662200/3598286)